# Pygame window is really laggy

Tags: python, pygame, lag

The pygame window gets really laggy when i try to run it. I have 132 lines of code so far and i have loads more stuff to add. While test-running i noticed that the game satrted lagging when i added the following bits of code in

```
class Game:
        def __init__(self):
            self.win = pygame.display
            self.d = self.win.set_mode((1200, 600))
            self.win.set_caption(" JUMP ")
            self.timee = 0

        def write(self, size, writing, color, x, y):
            font = pygame.font.SysFont("nirmalauisemilight", size)
            text = font.render(writing, True, color)
            self.d.blit(text, (x, y))

        def game_over(self):
            if b.y >= ba.y - b.side and self.timee > 5:
                while True:
                    self.write(200, "GAME OVER", (255, 0, 0), 20, 50)
                    self.write(50, "Press enter to satart a new game", (0, 255, 0), 100, 400)

                    pygame.event.get()
                    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                    if keys[pygame.K_RETURN]:
                        main()

                    g.win.flip()
```

AND

```
def draw(self):
        if g.timee < 5:
            pygame.draw.rect(g.d, (0, 255, 0), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(g.d, (255, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
```

`g.timee` is a variable i made so i can execute some functions after a cartain time into the game. `g.timee` is incremented by 0.01 in the main loop. I tried using time module's `time.time()` fucntion as well but it lagged the game even more. Any advice on how to reduce lagging would be appreciated.

EDIT

while looking through other questions i came across cPrifile and using that i got this data

```
        ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        0.000    0.000    0.204    0.204 testing.py:10(__init__)
            1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 testing.py:102(platforms)
          401    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 testing.py:21(game_over)
            1    0.020    0.020    9.688    9.688 testing.py:3(main)
            1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 testing.py:42(Block)
            1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 testing.py:43(__init__)
          401    0.003    0.000    0.016    0.000 testing.py:53(draw)
          401    0.002    0.000    0.006    0.000 testing.py:56(move)
          401    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 testing.py:63(jump_logic)
          401    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 testing.py:72(fall)
            1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 testing.py:84(Base)
            1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 testing.py:85(__init__)
            1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 testing.py:9(Game)
          401    0.001    0.000    0.009    0.000 testing.py:91(draw)
          401    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 testing.py:97(on_base)
```

I am not entirely sure what it means though.

EDIT 2

Here is the code i have so far for reference

```
import pygame, os, random

def main():
    os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
    pygame.init()
    acc_gravity = 0.009
    terminal_vel = 4

    class Game:
        def __init__(self):
            self.win = pygame.display
            self.d = self.win.set_mode((1200, 600), pygame.RESIZABLE)
            self.win.set_caption(" JUMP ")
            self.timee = 0
            self.platlist = []

        def write(self, size, writing, color, x, y):
            font = pygame.font.SysFont("nirmalauisemilight", size)
            text = font.render(writing, True, color)
            self.d.blit(text, (x, y))

        def game_over(self):
            if b.y >= ba.y - b.side and self.timee > 5:
                while True:
                    self.write(200, "GAME OVER", (255, 0, 0), 20, 50)
                    self.write(50, "Press enter to start a new game", (0, 255, 0), 100, 400)

                    pygame.event.get()
                    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                    if keys[pygame.K_RETURN]:
                        main()

                    g.win.flip()

        def control_counter(self):
            if self.timee > 100:
                self.timee = 100





    class Block:
        def __init__(self):
            self.x = 600
            self.y = 0
            self.side = 30
            self.speed = 2
            self.is_jumping = False
            self.gravity = 0.005
            self.jump_force = 10 
            self.jump_strength = 0.05 

        def draw(self):
            pygame.draw.rect(g.d, (0, 99, 99), (self.x, self.y, self.side, self.side))

        def move(self):
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                self.x += self.speed
            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                self.x -= self.speed

        def jump_logic(self):
            for event in events:
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        if self.is_jumping == False:
                            b.jump_force = 10
                            self.is_jumping = True


        def fall(self):
            self.y += self.gravity
            self.gravity += acc_gravity
            if self.gravity >= terminal_vel:
                self.gravity = terminal_vel

        def jump(self):
            self.y -= self.jump_force
            self.jump_force -= self.jump_strength
            if self.jump_force <= 0:
                self.jump_force = 0

    class Base:
        def __init__(self):
            self.x = 0
            self.y = 550
            self.width = 1200
            self.height = 20

        def draw(self):
            if g.timee < 5:
                pygame.draw.rect(g.d, (0, 255, 0), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(g.d, (255, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

        def on_base(self):
            if b.y >= self.y - b.side:
                b.y = self.y - b.side
                b.is_jumping = False

    class Platforms:
        def __init__(self):
            self.x = random.randint(1, 1100)
            self.y = random.randint(-300, 0)
            self.width = 100
            self.height = 20
            self.speed = random.randint(1, 4)

        def draw(self):
            pygame.draw.rect(g.d, (0, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

        def move(self):
            self.y += self.speed


    ba = Base()
    b = Block()
    g = Game()

    for  i in range(10):
        g.platlist.append(Platforms())


    game_loop = True
    while game_loop:

        g.timee += 0.01
        events = pygame.event.get()

        g.d.fill((98, 98, 98))

        b.draw()
        b.move()
        b.jump_logic()
        b.fall()

        if b.is_jumping:
            b.jump()

        ba.draw()
        ba.on_base()

        g.game_over()

        for plats in g.platlist:
            plats.draw()
            plats.move()

        g.win.flip()

        pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  Its  because my `pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)` was in the game loop. Not sure why this was causing lag but for anyone who might be having the same issue, dont put it in the main loop.

Comment: I haven't use pygame before, and I just ran your code just now and found out pygame.time.Clock().tick(60) is the culprit, I set it to 120 and it seem smoother, but it seem like putting it outside of the game loop is the right way.

Comment: It's weird that that's the culprit, as the tick method is supposed to cap the game at the FPS you pass into it, i.e. cause a delay *only* if the game runs faster than 60 FPS. It could maybe be that the clock initialization is slow (`pygame.time.Clock()`). You should create the clock before the main loop, not for every iteration.

Comment: Or it could be that its timing gets messed up since you're creating it every loop, so it delays more than it should. I would suggest you try it and rewrite your answer because the tick method should definitely be in the main loop and called every frame.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing anything obvious, so my guess would be due to your time delay mechanism.  Can you post on how you're delaying?  Your delay timing must not interfere with rendering/drawing.  Here's an example.

```
def gameloop1():  # delay interfering with drawing
   # delay by some long loop
   i = 0
   while i < 10000:
      i = i + 1

   if i == 10000:
      # execute some function

   # draw stuff
```

---

```
i = 0
def gameloop2():
   i = i + 1

   if i == 10000:
      # execute some function

   # draw stuff
```

In the example gameloop1 will have some delay before each draw, where as gameloop2 will not and still allows you to perform delay.  Also don't use this incremental as a delay mechanism as it will varies on different system speed, use time base instead.

Comment: I tried using time  function but it caused even worse lags so i kinda had to use it. Hopefully i can use time function if the lag is fixed